# HTML Templates Slots and Teats on a bull

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom, slot

Can someone confirm, or point me to proposed documentation for, the rules for matching a Host Element's "slot=" designator with a Template's `<slot>` tag?

I had very much hoped that it was a simply NAME matching process regardless of depth/position of the corresponding Slots in the Light DOM versus the Shadow DOM, but, sadly, it appears that ancestry lineage is an overriding factor. IOW a child slot in the Light DOM will ***not*** populate a grandchild slot in the shadow DOM even if names match. Is this correct?

It reminds me very much of COBOL's MOVE CORR rules regarding Levels but surely this restriction presupposes the main-page author's intimate knowledge of the Component's Shadow DOM rendering SLOTs unfit for purpose?

Browser: Chrome 58.0.3029.96 (64-bit)

[This](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/shadow/#finding-slots-and-slotables) seems to say descendant depth should not be an issue as long as roots are ok. Or have I read it wrong?

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<template id="contact-template">
    <style>
        :host { border: solid 1px #ccc; border-radius: 0.5rem; padding: 0.5rem; margin: 0.5rem; }
        b { display: inline-block; width: 5rem; }
    </style>
    <b>HELLO</b><br/>
    <b>Name</b>: <slot name="fullName"><slot name="firstName"></slot> <slot name="lastName"></slot></slot><br>
    <b>Email</b>: <slot name="email">Unknown</slot><br>
    <b>Address</b>: <slot name="address">Unknown</slot>
    <slot></slot>
</template>
<script>
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var contacts = document.getElementById('contacts').children;
    var template = document.getElementById('contact-template').content;
    alert("Hello"+contacts.length);
        document.getElementById("d").attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).appendChild(template.cloneNode(true));

    return;

    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++)
        contacts[i].attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).appendChild(template.cloneNode(true));
});
</script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">

<p id="demo">Click the button to change the text in this paragraph.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<div id="contacts">
<div id="d">
<span slot="email">span it</span>
  <div name="removeToWork">
        <div slot="fullName">Commit Queue</div>
        (<a slot="email" href="mailto:commit-queue@webkit.org">commit-queue@webkit.org</a>)<br>
        <span slot="address">One Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA 95014</span>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}

function load() {

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **slotable** (an element with the `slot` attribute) will be inserted in the shadow DOM only if it's a direct child of the shadow DOM host.

From the [specification](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/shadow/#finding-slots-and-slotables):

> 4. For each slotable **child of host**, slotable, in tree order, run these substeps:

So grandchilds won't match.

```
<div id="host">
  <div slot="s1">Can match</div>
  <div slot="s2">Can match</div>
  <div>
     <div slot="s3">Won't match</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping that "tree order" included recursiveness. Nevertheless, surely this example contradicts what you are saying and my personal experience: - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/slot summary/detail elements not real nodes/children?

Comment: Do not confuse slot element and slotable element: the direct child constraint  refers to slotable. A slot can be a grandchild in the shadow tree.

Comment: You Bewdy! Thanks mate. Makes much more sense.